# How to create heroku server with multiple endpoints for square payment?

Tags: java, android, heroku, square-connect, square

I'm working through this example processing android payments through square: https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-server-quickstart
    And while the example server with a single endpoint works (inside the index.js file), I am stuck trying to figure out how to create a server with two or more endpoints.

In the index.js file, i've tried copying the app.post() endpoint a second time, but this doesn't work.

```
app.post('/charge1DollarForAlex', async (request, response) => {
  const requestBody = request.body;
  const locations = await locationsApi.listLocations();
  const locationId = locations.locations[0].id;

  const createOrderRequest = {
    idempotency_key: crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex'),
    order: {
      line_items: [
        {
          name: "Pay Alex $1.00 ",
          quantity: "1",
          base_price_money: {
            amount: 100,
            currency: "USD"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

//more code.......

app.post('/charge5DollarsForAlex', async (request, response) => {
  const requestBody = request.body;
  const locations = await locationsApi.listLocations();
  const locationId = locations.locations[0].id;

  const createOrderRequest = {
    idempotency_key: crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex'),
    order: {
      line_items: [
        {
          name: "Pay Alex $5.00 ",
          quantity: "1",
          base_price_money: {
            amount: 500,
            currency: "USD"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Ultimately, i'd like to be able to have the android app charge different rates, but can't figure out how to make that dollar amount editable, or how to process two charges of different amounts within the same app.

Comment: The example app there is just a basic Express application. Technically by duplicating of the `app.post()` with a new route should effectively create another endpoint that you could call for charging $5.00 USD. Typically you'd send along some other info when sending your nonce to indicate what the buyer might be wanting to purchase (item IDs for a cart, or amounts for a donation) and you'd just want to parse that in your backend inside of the body of that `app.post()` function.

Comment: How would I go about duplicating the app.post() with a new route?  I'm not clear on what I should be changing............do you know of any good tutorials or resources that might be useful in getting more familiar with this topic?

Comment: Mozilla actually has a tutorial on Express https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes. I've linked the part on Routing there, that should help give some clarity on how to create new endpoints. You can also always ask for help in https://squ.re/slack to get help from some Square engineers.